# What are some considerations while preparing for an all day trip in NYC?

Tags: infant, travel

We're going to be in NYC on foot and taking the subway around all day. Or daughter is 3 months old.
We're going to bring our usual diaper bag, a baby carrier, a sling, extra change of clothes, water bottle(for mom & dad), ...

What other things should we think about bringing? She feeds exclusively on the breast so no need for bottles.

Comment: See also [Can I use a stroller for my infant in Chicago's public transportation?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/1654)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly reconsider about the stroller.  If you don't have one, consider borrowing one (keep in mind that for a 3 month old you'll need to have a stroller suitable for an infant, so no umbrella strollers or anything that requires the child sit upright).

The reasons for a stroller:

- Storage!  Most strollers have some area where you can put bags, diapers, wipes, etc..  This can be invaluable when out and about, particularly if you're going to be out for an entire day.  You're going to need a lot of things (diapers, wipes, spare clothes, a changing pad, etc. gets to be a pretty bulky load), and if you have any plans on doing some shopping you'll want all the help you can get.
- The stroller will provide opportunities for both you and your daughter to rest.  While your daughter may sleep just fine while you're holding her, not being able to put her down the entire day will take its toll on you both, even if you and your partner take turns carrying her.  This will also make meals much more manageable for you.
- Space.  While at first glance having a stroller would seem to create problems regarding space, the trade off is that you can use it to gain more space for your daughter in crowded situations.  People are generally very accommodating for families with small children, and on a crowded subway the space your stroller takes up means your baby is less likely to get squished against a stranger.

Comment: Very good points for bringing a stroller.

Comment: Having just had the day in NYC where I carried my 12 lb daughter and a backpack, a stroller would have been really nice! The only issue would have been on the subway, many time the train was kind of packed. But I think the pros would outweigh the cons. :)

Comment: "People are very accommodating" does not match my experience of Manhattan.  I'm a born and bred New Yorker, but crowds can be quite pushy.

Answer (score 2):

You are nuts!

Currently, it is cold in NYC.

1/ Get a big, warm blanket .. polar fleece is good .. big enough to cover the stroller and big enough to cover and warm you both when feeding.

2/ Prepare all three of you for adverse weather .. cold, rain, snow.

3/ Bring more water than you think in necessary.

4/ Bring at least twice the diapers, wipes, etc. than you think is necessary.

5/ Bring a few large trash bags as they are good for keeping things dry if rain goes crazy.

Good luck!

Comment: Lol! It's actually going to be high 40s without any snow or rain. :) We won't have a stroller but we definitely will bundle her up. Good thoughts about being prepared for anything.

Comment: +1 for "Bring at least twice the diapers, wipes, etc. than you think is necessary."!